# Best way to store points

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, point

I'm creating a game similar to Battleship. I need to store a grid of fields on the board. Each field value is its current status - empty/ship.
I declared 2 dimensional array like shown below:

```
//from createEmptyBoard() function in loop
playerBoard[x][y] = FIELD_EMPTY;
```

Now I would like to rewrite the code using classes.
I defined the classes **GameBoard** and **Field**

Class **GameBoard** (TypeScript):

```
class GameBoard {
  private verticalFields: number;
  private horizontalFields: number;
  private fields = Array<Field>();

  constructor(verticalFields: number, horizontalFields: number) {
    this.verticalFields = verticalFields;
    this.horizontalFields = horizontalFields;
  }

  private initializeEmptyFields() {
    for (let x = 0; x < this.verticalFields; x++) {
      for (let y = 0; y < this.horizontalFields; y++) {
        this.addField(x, y);
      }
    }
  }

  private addField(x, y) {
    this.fields.push(new Field(x, y));
  }
//...
```

Class **Field** (TypeScript):

```
class Field {
  private x: number;
  private y: number;
  private status: number;

  private static readonly FIELD_EMPTY = 0;
  private static readonly FIELD_SHIP = 1;
  private static readonly FIELD_MISS = 2;
  private static readonly FIELD_HIT = 3;


  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.status = Field.FIELD_EMPTY;
  }

  public setAsEmpty() {
    this.status = Field.FIELD_EMPTY;
  }

  public setAsShip() {
    this.status = Field.FIELD_SHIP;
  }
```

In another method I check if the field clicked by the user is empty or has a ship. In the old code I did it in this way:

```
function fieldIsEmpty(x,y) {
  return playerBoard[x][y] == FIELD_FIELD_EMPTY;
}
```

But now I have no idea how to get a field by coordinate. Looking for object with *x* and *y* property that I'm looking for in loop isn't the most efficient way.

**How to store fields with possibility to get one by its coordinate?**

Answer (score 0):

you can write function like this on `GameBoard`:

```
public getField(x, y) {
    return this.fields[x + this.verticalFields * y];
}
```